# Typeset whole note as full measure in 6/8 time in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

I'm trying to copy a song from a book in which they were using a whole note to represent a full measure in 6/8 time.

If I try to use the whole note duration in Lilypond (1), it lasts 8/8 and everything gets unaligned. So far I could only replicate the song using half + quarter notes with a tie, but if I could replace it by a whole note it would be much cleaner.

I've also tried to do a half note + space and hide the stem, but it doesn't look very good.

Is there a way to simply change the length of the whole note to match 6/8?

Comment: Exercise your prerogatives as an editor: replace them with dotted minims (half notes), and you'll have the standard notation for 6/8 meter. Semibreve (whole note) lengths are only used for whole-measure rests in 6/8. I see no good reason to perpetuate a bad and somewhat confusing notational quirk.

Comment: Sure, you can just say `c1*6/8` to get a note that *looks* like a whole note but *sounds* for 6/8. But I agree that simply correcting the score is the better option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start with a note (or rest), add a time value, then add a multiplication symbol with the fraction of rhythmic value, you will arrive at your desired note.

`a1*6/8`

So, for instance, `a1` means "the note A at the full value of a whole note." But `a1*6/8` means "the note A, written as a whole note, but taking up only sixth-eighths of the value of a whole note." This fraction may incidentally be whatever you want.

I've more often used a whole note to indicate a note lasting the entire measure when it's *longer* than usual (e.g., `a1*11/8` to make a whole note fill a measure of 11/8 time; or `s1*24` to mean "make an invisible spacer rest that lasts the length of twenty-four whole notes"), but marking a whole note to mean *less than* the normal value seems out of the ordinary. For 6/8 time, a dotted half note is normal to fill in the measure.

One last note about rests. You *do* see a "whole" rest fill a measure of any time signature. In Lilypond, that is not represented by `r1` --- that will still get you the whole rest taking up its normal value --- but rather by `R1` which denotes a "MultiMeasureRest," which will always appear *as* a whole note, but also be directly centered in the measure.

As found in the documentation on [full-measure rests](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/writing-rests#full-measure-rests), the number after an **uppercase R** will denote such a rest. Therefore, since `2.` fills the entirety of a 6/8 time signature (as well as 3/4), use `R2.`. You will end up seeing something that looks more like what you normally would encounter.

Answer (score 4):

LilyPond offers the choice between full-bar and normal rests as `R` and `r`.  The same for notes is not available.  As mentioned in the comments, `c1*6/8` will take you half the way to your wish.  However, this kind of full-bar note is almost only employed for baroque bordun notes (usually a breve instead of a semibreve head) and then, like full-bar rests, the placement of the note is in the *middle* of the bar rather than at its start.

It does not sound like what you are having here, so it would be musically advisable to use `c2.` instead, namely the musically correct duration.  Or possibly `c4.~c4.` depending on how strong the subdivision of the bar is rhythmically.